# Can JavaScript be the only language used in a project?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started learning JavaScript a while back and it didn't take long for me to realize that JS relies heavily on HTML/CSS (there isn't even a way to get an input from the user using just JS unless you use prompt or HTML).

However, I love the language itself and I was wondering if there is any way to have a project run on JUST JS. (Or if there is another language that's language is as beautiful and simple as JavaScript but still has the practicality of Java or C++. I find Python/Ruby's syntax to be odd, sorry).

I know this isn't the usual question here at Stack Overflow, but I'm somewhat new to this and there's no other clear, definitive answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use JavaScript on the server, just like Python, Ruby, ... https://nodejs.org/

Comment: For the browser, React lets you write HTML in JavaScript, and depending om how you want to approach it, CSS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at Node.js. Which is a backend server framework that uses Javascript as the language.

But if you want to display user interface code to browsers, you still can't get away from HTML and Javascript.

Comment: You still can't get away from HTML and **CSS**, did you mean? The OP is fine with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with an user in a browser, you must need html, or prompts as you said otherwise the user have nothing to do there :).

And If you are looking a way to execute javascript at server side
Look at, [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) that take advantage of [V8 JavaScript Engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)

Another option is [io.js](https://iojs.org/en/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

With Node.js, you can write a project beyond web.